# Concated Oracle statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, type-conversion, migration

I have this statement in Oracle:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2018.11.19 13:14:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Is there an equivalent statement in SQL Server for this?

Comment: `'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss'` isn't a valid date. `'2018.11.11` would be. Also, the `TO_CHAR` and `TO_TIMESTAMP` functions aren't closed, so that would also generate an error.

Comment: Oh I understood something wrong, edited it now

Comment: Could you please mention your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use format

```
declare @d datetime='2018.11.19 13:14:00';

select format(@d,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff') as date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
select format(getdate(),'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss')
```